# How to bind image in Gridview using xml parsing in windows metro app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm working on my first Windows 8 app. I'm trying to display a GridView populated with Image and Image description. I want to get my data from an XML file I created. I found the ItemSource property of the GridView and I try to bind my XML file to it but I can't do this.

Please tell me right way to do this task. thanx

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information than this to try to help you.  What have you tried?  What exactly isn't working?  What does your XML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind an XML file directly to `GridView.ItemsSource`, you need to parse it first into an object. I'd create a class with all data to be displayed in `GridView`:

```
public class GridViewItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}
```

The next step is to parse the XML file into a list of `GridViewItem`s:

```
var xmlString = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var Items = xml.Element("rootNode").Elements("itemNode").Select(i => new GridViewItem
    {
        Description = (string)i.Element("descriptionNode"),
        Image = ParseImage(i.Element("imageNode"))
    }).ToList();
```

I've assumed the tags in your XML are `rootNode`, `itemNode`, `descriptionNode` and `imageNode`. Also I don't know how your image data is stored in XML. The logic to convert it to an `ImageSource` should be in `ParseImage()`.

The only thing left is to assign the `Items` list above to a property in your view model serving as you `DataContext` and bind it to `ItemsSource`:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

This is the basic idea. There's a lot of details missing in my answer but that's best I can do based on your question.