# using custom data resource in Metro Apps C#

Tags: c#, parsing, xaml, microsoft-metro

i'm new to Metro apps. i wanted to display Image and some data along with it, using ListView control. for that pupose, i've searched and found that i've to place my custom data resource. i've got this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextListCollectionTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500" Height="130">
        <Border Height="110" Width="110" Margin="10,10,0,10">
            <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Aellus nec ipsum tempor id laoreet viverra" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="350" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
            <TextBlock Text="Phasellus faucibus" 
                   Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="350" Height="14" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9" Opacity="0.49"/>
            <TextBlock Text="A Proin leo nulla, scelerisque non congue nec, facilisis a tellus. Sed varius rhoncus metus, et condimentum ipsum luctus ullamcorper." 
                   Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="350" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

now so far i could understand, i have to parse it. i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342851/win-8-metro-app-c-sharp-multiple-itemtemplate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826510/how-to-bind-image-in-gridview-using-xml-parsing-in-windows-metro-app) but could not understand. Assuming i have no/little about parsing, plz provide some helpful link/solution wich enables me to understand the science to utilize it.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the data you have to bind a list of objects to your listview.

So say you have class called person like this:

```
class Person{
    string Name{get; set;}
}
```

In your code-behind in the load for example you should do something like this:

```
List<Person> people = getPeople();  // Load your data from somewhere
this.myListView.ItemsSource = people;
```

In your datatemplate you can then bind to the properties like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```